# Recommendations for reading in Constructive Mathematics

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

I'm looking preferably for any **survey articles** on constructivism in the Philosophy of Mathematics - including Intuitionism in the tradition of Brouwer.

Hopefully such an article(s) will cover:

1. Motivation (for mathematical and philosophical) for constructivism/intuitionism
2. The main proponents of the view (including their differing stances) and a tracing of its development since Brouwer
3. An exposition of the main components of constructivism/intuitionism in the context of the Philosophy of Mathematics
4. Notable objections and substantiations of them
5. Potential for future work, including modern reconstructions of the theory

Rather than a list of articles for each point - a lot of which I already have - I'm hoping someone can point me towards a full expository reference covering all of these thoughts.

Thanks

Comment: To get a modern idea I strongly recommend to read the introduction of the HoTT book: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Homotopy+Type+Theory+--+Univalent+Foundations+of+Mathematics

Comment: I second the HoTT suggestion. Also if you can read Russian, there is an excellent survey by Albert Dragalin called _Mathematical Intuitionism: Introduction to Proof Theory_.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan - there is an [english translation](http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Intuitionism-Introduction-Translations-Monographs/dp/0821845209) published by American Mathematical Society in 1988.

Comment: A maybe useful link to a 1973  article by Graham Priest ( see page 118 of the original paper version) http://grahampriest.net/publications/papers/#1973  ( A Bedside Readers Guide to the Conventionalist Philosophy of Mathematics, with J. Bell and et. al., 115–132. Proc. Bertrand Russell Memorial Logic Conference, Denmark 1971, Leeds, 1973.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A good point to start with is *SEP*; see the entries on [Intuitionism in the Philosophy of Mathematics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionism/) and [Constructive Mathematics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-constructive/).

Of course, if you want some book references, following @Paul Ross suggestion, I will add :

> Errett Bishop, *Foundations of constructive analysis* (1967)
>
> Errett Bishop & Douglas Bridges *Constructive Analysis* (1985)
>
> Michael Beeson, *Foundations of constructive mathematics* (1985).

All of them deal with the "mathematical side" and not with the philosophical.

About this one, see :

> Michael Dummett, *Elements of Intuitionism* (2nd ed, 2000).

Comment: The SEP article on Constructive Mathematics is written by Douglas Bridges, who is a very reputable source on the current state of the field.  He's also given a good introductory lecture on the subject, with slides available at http://www.masfak.ni.ac.rs/cmfp2013/Nis%20lecture%20170113.pdf .

Comment: @Mauro Many thanks - the SEP articles seem to be very thorough.